# NestJS: "NotFoundException" from my service does not work correclty if I use it in a loop

Tags: nestjs

I have a simple "findOne exercice" service that throw a "NotFoundException" if the ID of the exercice does not exist in the database.

Here is the code from this service :

```js
  async findOne(id: string | Exercice) {
    if (!isValidObjectId(id)) {
      throw new BadRequestException('ID is not valid');
    }

    const exercice = await this.exerciceModel
      .findById(id)
      .populate('bodyPart targetMuscle')
      .select('-__v');

    if (!exercice) {
      throw new NotFoundException('exercice not found');
    }

    return exercice;
  }
```

When I create a program, I need to make sure the exercice I send in the body exist in the database. So in my "create program service" I call my exercice service like this.

```js
  async create(createProgramDto: CreateProgramDto) {

    const { user, exercices } = createProgramDto;
    
    // some code

    exercices.forEach(async (element) => {
     await this.exerciceService.findOne(element.exercice)
    });

    const createProgram = new this.programModel(createProgramDto);
    return createProgram.save();
  }
```

What I expect, is that my "exercice sercice" throw a "notfoundexception" if one of the exercice in the body does not exist. Instead, I got this error :

```
/home/jeremy/src/apps/API/my-exercices/src/modules/exercice/exercice.service.ts:62
      throw new NotFoundException('exercice not found');
            ^
NotFoundException: exercice not found
    at ExerciceService.findOne (/home/jeremy/src/apps/API/my-exercices/src/modules/exercice/exercice.service.ts:62:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at /home/jeremy/src/apps/API/my-exercices/src/modules/program/program.service.ts:29:6
```

Here is how I send data to create a program :

```json
{
    "title": "Test",
    "user": "634c1bd3c3d17e1b50c2b946",
    "exercices": [
        {
            "exercice": "637d116882ce1f7cc732d83c",
            "totalSet": "1",
            "rest": "1"
        },
        {
            "exercice": "637d116882ce1f7cc2d83c",
            "totalSet": "1",
            "rest": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I did try to use the service without loop (by adding an ID in the codebase) and it works. But if I use it in a loop, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype` methods do not properly handle asynchronous code, so while you may use `async/await` and `try/catch` inside it, the execution of those promises will be in the background and outside of the scope of the request (and thus Nest's exception filter) meaning you have dangling promises. The best option if you absolutely need to iterate over an array and do asynchronous methods is use  `await Promise.allSettled(array.map(async(arrayObject) => someAsyncFunction))` so that you actually wait for all the promises to reject or resolve

Comment: Thank you. I don't have the error anymore, but is there any way to reject the exception from the exercice service ? I managed to get what I wanted like this : https://pastebin.com/R1iexe1i but it's a bit tricky and not very clean

Comment: If you don't care about gathering all the rejections and just rejecting directly you can use  `Promise.all()` instead.